# Layout constraints are not working iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I added leading | trailing | top | height constraints but the view is not visible.

```
  let view = UIView()
  view.backgroundColor = .orange
  self.addSubview(view)
    
  NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
        view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 100),
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
  ])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should disable `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` when adding the view as a subview. This means the system won't create a set of constraints that duplicate the behaviour specified by the view’s autoresizing mask.

Assuming your constraints are correct, you should see your view appear after setting the property to false.

```
let view = UIView()
view.backgroundColor = .orange
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.addSubview(view)
    
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
    view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 100),
    view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
])
```